# csv reformatting with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file cointaining a lot of lines in this format:

```
firstname     ; lastname     ; age     ;
```

(*it's a bit more complex but that's basically the file*)

so the fields are of a fixed length, padded with spaces and with a semicolon in between the fields.

I would like to have it so:

```
firstname, lastname, age,
```

(commas and no fixed width)

I have replaced the commas with regexp but I would like to also trim the end of the strings. But I don't know how to do this.

The following is my start, but I can't manage to get a ".TrimEnd()" in there. I have also thought of trying a "-replace("  ", " ") but I can't integrate it in this expression:

```
Get-Content .\Bestand.txt | %{$data= [regex]::split($_, ';'); [string]:: join(',', $data)}
```

Can I get some information on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-replace` operator takes a regular expression, which you can use to remove all leading and trailing spaces:

```
Get-Content .\Bestand.txt | 
    Foreach-Object { $_ -replace ' *; *',',' } |
    Out-File .\Bestand.csv -Encoding OEM
```

Comment: -replace also takes an array (or output of a pipe) as input: `(cat .\bestand.txt) -replace ' *; *',',' | Out-File .\Bestand.csv -Encoding OEM`

Comment: There was an arbitrary amount of spaces so this worked as a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you replace each occurrence of 'space;space' with a comma (assuming the replaced characters do not appear within a valid value), so the end result will look like:

```
firstname,lastname,age
```

Keeping it like the following is not a good idea cause now some of your headers (property names) start with a space:

```
"firstname, lastname, age,"
```

Give this a try (work on a copy of the file):

```
(Get-Content .\Bestand.txt) | 
foreach {$_ -replace ' ; ',','} |
out-file .\Bestand.txt
```

Now it's easy to import and process the file with `Import-Csv` cmdlet.

Comment: I would suggest accounting for arbitrary amount of whitespace on either side of the `;`, by using `$_ -replace '\s*;\s*', ','`

Comment: That's valid as well, I'd use + instead of *

Answer (score 0):

Since you already create something CSV-*ish*, I'd go all the way and create proper CSV:

```
$cols = "firstname","lastname","age","rest"

Import-Csv "C:\input.txt" -Delimiter ";" -Header $cols | % {
  foreach ($property in $_.PsObject.Properties) {
    $property.Value = ([string]$property.Value).Trim()
  }
  $_
} | Export-Csv "C:\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```